# Sql Database analyse, where should files go?

Tags: sql-server, database, file, database-design, file-io

I'm analyzing a system which has routine Accounting actions and data plus Customer Relation Management (CRM). In the CRM part of the system we record customers' calls and save them somewhere, we may save customers' Pictures, Logos, Signatures, Scanned documents and so on. So we should deal with a wide range of files (sound, image, pdf, word documents, etc ...)

I need help deciding where to keep files.

In the old system we kept files on Hard Disk Drive space and saved the path to the database, and at the time of need we would open the file using it address. I think (correct me if I'm wrong) it is not a good solution to keep files on HDD because :

1. We lose data integrity. The file names may get changed (renamed, moved, deleted, overwritten) for any reason, resulting to the wrong path in database.
2. Moving the whole data (moving server) would be a time consuming process, let's say we have 1,000,000 files totally reaching 20 GB. If I want to move 1 million files from one computer to another, assuming that my PC does tolerates it and does not burn, it will take a long time to move files (I/O time for copying a lot of small files is more than copying a big file) but moving a single file of 20 GB data (the database file) would be much faster.
3. It's easier to backup the data in database compared with copying files. Using Full Backup and Differential Backup we can backup the right portion of data at once, and we can also make a regular schedule to this for us.

and maybe other reasons ...

---

Here my questions go.

- Does storing files in db and growing the db infect on regular db actions? Like selects, updates, querying tables and so on. I mean if I store files (CRM data) in the same database (as for Accounting data) does my Accounting system get slower?
- Where should I keep the files? In a normal table? Or I should separate the database to two files? One for typical data and one for files?
- Does Sql Server 2012 have a space limit? If my file part of db grows and for example reaches 500 GB (assuming that the Disk Drive has enough space) does Sql Server handle it?
- What Cons may be there using database for storing files? I just talked about Pros, and there may be Cons. If there is, what are they?

Comment: According to the [Maximum Capacity Specifications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) for SQL Server 2012, the max. file size is **16 terabytes** - and your database can have **multiple** files. Good enough?

Comment: @marc_s thanks for your answer, but should I keep files like other data in db or separate my db into two files and keep files separated from other data? Does it affect other data at all? And are there any **cons**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a really good paper by Microsoft Research called [To Blob or Not To Blob](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525).

Their conclusion after a large number of performance tests and analysis is this:

- if your pictures or document are typically below 256K in size, storing them in a database `VARBINARY` column is more efficient
- if your pictures or document are typically over 1 MB in size, storing them in the filesystem is more efficient (and with SQL Server 2008's `FILESTREAM` attribute, they're still under transactional control and part of the database)
- in between those two, it's a bit of a toss-up depending on your use

If you decide to put your pictures into a SQL Server table, I would strongly recommend using a separate table for storing those pictures - do not store the employee foto in the employee table - keep them in a separate table. That way, the Employee table can stay lean and mean and very efficient, assuming you don't always need to select the employee foto, too, as part of your queries.

For filegroups, check out [Files and Filegroup Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx) for an intro. Basically, you would either create your database with a separate filegroup for large data structures right from the beginning, or add an additional filegroup later. Let's call it "LARGE_DATA".

Now, whenever you have a new table to create which needs to store `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `VARBINARY(MAX)` columns, you can specify this file group for the large data:

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
     (....... define the fields here ......)
     ON Data                   -- the basic "Data" filegroup for the regular data
     TEXTIMAGE_ON LARGE_DATA   -- the filegroup for large chunks of data
```

Check out the MSDN intro on filegroups, and play around with it!

Comment: The LOB data is already stored out of row, and I don't see how would putting employee pictures separately increase efficiency (unless you have a habit of doing SELECT *). You have the pointer overhead both ways. Management issues are more valid argument imnsho.

Comment: FileStream is great here because you DO get the advantages - referential integrity and... making coherent backups. +1 - for knowing about this feature that most people seem to prefer to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you check the FILETABLE feature in SQL Server 2012:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx

Unless you're generally dealing with files of very small size, you'd probably get better performance. And I'd almost always trade a bit of perf for consistency anyway.

With FILETABLE, the files are stored in filesystem, but transactionally managed by SQL Server. So you get the best of both worlds - integrity, unified security and management, ease of programming access, and even performance.